# Get the "user agent" string from a new Google Chrome browser session from bash

Tags: command-line, bash, google-chrome, 22.04

I want to get the [User Agent HTTP request header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) string from a new Google Chrome browser session (just opened) from bash and put it in a variable.

Here is the pseudo-code:

```
USER_AGENT="$(google-chrome --user-agent)"
echo "$USER_AGENT"
```

Output example:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

If it is not possible to do this with the `google-chrome` command, what is an equivalent workaround?

Comment: I think you need to be much more specific by explaining what you want, start by explaining what you mean by "user agent". If you mean the [User Agent HTTP request header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent), please link to that to be specific.

Comment: It sounds like you want to get the User Agent string from a specific browser session from bash, but I'm not sure that is possible right away.

Comment: It is not that it sounds, it is. Of what I have written, what is it that is unclear to you? I have tried to explain as much as possible what I am asking.

Comment: You haven't described how you want to identify the browser session - is it by the process PID? I'm still not sure if it's possible at all. If you want to identify the session by "the browser window I'm looking at", I think you'll have to code some eye-tracking software yourself.. 

Comment: I want to get the [User Agent HTTP request header][1] string from a new (just opened) Google Chrome browser session from bash and put it in a variable.

Comment: Ok, I changed the question, now it should be more explanatory. It took me an hour to make it as understandable as possible.

Comment: Why do you need this, and for which purpose do you need the output? This might be an XY-problem, where an alternative solution is more suited.

Comment: I'm unclear why this is asked in this forum, as there's no indication that the OP is running Ubuntu, or if Ubuntu is part of the question/proposed solution. I'd recommend that this question instead get posted over on Stack Overflow. A good starting point for research before reposting might be here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13803621/shell-script-aix-extracting-os-and-browser-information-from-user-agent-strin

Comment: Stackoverflow understood and easily solved my problem, no XY problems, etc but a complete and fully understandable question as it is.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73571131

Comment: Then it seems [so] was the right place to post, and not Ask Ubuntu. You could remove your post here, since you crossposted to [so].

Comment: @richbl There's the `22.04` tag since the first edition of the question. That's clearly an Ubuntu version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you a 90% solution. You can get what you need from there.

```
a=$(curl -G https://www.whatismybrowser.com/guides/the-latest-user-agent/chrome)

echo "$a" | fgrep -e "Latest Chrome" -e '<span class="code">' | 
sed -E 's/^ *//;s/(<\/.*>)$//;s/^(<.*>)//'
```

Edit: Better `sed` syntax, it was bugging me. The Stackoverflow answer is much more elegant, this just harvests OSINT from a site.

Comment: You deserve equally the best answer. XD